# Create simple oop arithmetic functions

Tags: php, oop

I am new to oop.  I just can't debug this simple code. I don't know why the arguments don't get passed through it.

```
class MyCalculator {  
    private $_fval, $_sval;  

    public function add($fval, $sval) {  
        return $this->_fval + $this->_sval;  
    }  

    public function subtract($fval, $sval) {  
        return $this->_fval - $this->_sval;  
    }  

    public function multiply($fval, $sval) {  
        return $this->_fval * $this->_sval;  
    }  

    public function divide($fval, $sval) {  
        return $this->_fval / $this->_sval;  
    }  
}  

$mycalc = new MyCalculator;   
echo $mycalc-> add(12,6); 
echo $mycalc-> multiply(12,6); 
echo $mycalc-> subtract(12,6);  
echo $mycalc-> divide(12,6);
```

Comment: as you pass the values directly to the functions, you dont use `$this`, the first one is just:  `return $fval + $sval; ` http://ideone.com/LFZywN

Comment: Then when do you use $this?

Comment: When you are addressing a class property, not when you are addressing a function parameter

Comment: when you add the values in to the object - this is getting to broad for S.O there's lots of great basic OOP tutorials available

Comment: Can you please suggest a a good tutorial for OOP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted your code to work using the class properties you would do something like this

The constructor is used to load the class properties and then each method does not need its own parameters

```
class MyCalculator {  
    private $_fval, $_sval;  

    public function __construct($fval, $sval) {
        $this->_fval = $fval;
        $this->_sval = sval;
    }

    public function add() {  
        return $this->_fval + $this->_sval;  
    }  

    public function subtract() {  
        return $this->_fval - $this->_sval;  
    }  

    public function multiply() {  
        return $this->_fval * $this->_sval;  
    }  

    public function divide() {  
        return $this->_fval / $this->_sval;  
    }  
}  

$mycalc = new MyCalculator(12,6);   
echo $mycalc-> add(); 
echo $mycalc-> multiply(); 
echo $mycalc-> subtract();  
echo $mycalc-> divide();
```

Now to correct the way you were doing it

```
class MyCalculator {  

    //private $_fval, $_sval;  not used so not needed

    public function add($fval, $sval) {  
        return $fval + $sval;  
    }  

    public function subtract($fval, $sval) {  
        return $fval - $sval;  
    }  

    public function multiply($fval, $sval) {  
        return $fval * $sval;  
    }  

    public function divide($fval, $sval) {  
        return $fval / $sval;  
    }  
}  


$mycalc = new MyCalculator();   
echo $mycalc-> add(12,6); 
echo $mycalc-> multiply(12,6); 
echo $mycalc-> subtract(12,6);  
echo $mycalc-> divide(12,6);
```

Now it would probably be better to make this a static class as its basically just a function library and has no instance data.

```
class MyCalculator {  

    public static function add($fval, $sval) {  
        return $fval + $sval;  
    }  

    public static function subtract($fval, $sval) {  
        return $fval - $sval;  
    }  

    public static function multiply($fval, $sval) {  
        return $fval * $sval;  
    }  

    public static function divide($fval, $sval) {  
        return $fval / $sval;  
    }  
}  

//$mycalc = new MyCalculator(12,6); static classes dont need to be instantiated
echo MyCalculator::add(12,6); 
echo MyCalculator::multiply(12,6); 
echo MyCalculator::subtract(12,6);  
echo MyCalculator::divide(12,6);
```

Comment: i was to lazy to type this up :-) now give a demo where the arguments are passed in to the object not in the constructor :-)

Comment: @Dagon Ok, and I will raise you a Static class

Answer (score 2):

`$this` refers to the object in which the functions are defined by your class. If you'll notice, you're using $_fval in your class properties and $fval in your method parameters. These are not related.

```
class MyCalculator
{
     public function add($fval, $sval)
     {
         return $fval + $sval;
     }
...
}
```

If you are trying to set and use the properties of the object so that you can call them later, you need to set their values in your method:

```
class MyCalculator
{
     private $_fval, $_sval;
     public function add($fval, $sval)
     {
         $this->_fval = $fval;
         $this->_sval = $sval;
         return $this->_fval + $this->_sval;
     }
...
}
```

In your use case, it does you no good to set and use these private properties. It's redundant. They aren't connected or dependent unless you make them so.

Properties are set so they can be used by either methods of the object or visible publicly and have nothing to do with the parameters sent to the methods. You named them similarly, but this doesn't connect them in any way.